# Vimeo Api can not be created

Tags: vimeo

I m trying to create an app on Vimeo web but it prompts that "verify your email first" I have already verified the email.
Please help me out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHwCx.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Vimeo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your https://vimeo.com/settings and verify your email address.

If you're unable to do so, contact Vimeo at https://vimeo.com/help/contact.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you try to create your first app on the "My Apps" page. I got the same error OP described.

The solution is to go to any other page where you still see the "Create App" button at the top right. For example: https://developer.vimeo.com/

This worked for me. I doubt Vimeo support even knows about this bug.